# how to connect web server to my eclipse android application?

Tags: android, json, eclipse, web-hosting

I would like to read data from my web link "http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.php" its a php file where i converted all of my data in JSON format . In browser i can able to see my JSON output from this link when i try to use this link in android i receive the following error : `unknownhostexception unable to resolve the host:www.xxxxxxxxx.com : No address associated with hostname.`

my sample code is

```
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    String link1="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/read_data.php";
    String resp="";


  try{
            resp=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(link1, postParameters);

            Log.i("Web Host Response : ","Resp : "+resp.toString());

      }
      catch(Exception e)
                {

                Log.i("Log tag","Error "+e.getMessage());

                }
```

friends please help me to solve this problem

and my manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
package="com.example.recordingsystem"

android:versionCode="1"    

android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk

    android:minSdkVersion="16"

    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >


    <activity

        android:name=".MainActivity"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

     <activity

        android:name="com.example.recordingsystem.home_page"  

        android:screenOrientation="portrait"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: check permissions and check that your url is valid or not and check if you have valid internet connection.

Comment: did you add permission for INTERNET in your manifest file?

Comment: @perfection yes i have added permission in my manifest file  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Post here your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
And one more question is browser that you had mentioned is browser on your mobile?

Comment: @anatol i have posted my manifest file and my checked with crome and mozilla fire fox browsers

Answer (score 0):

Add following permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: yes i have added permission in my manifest file <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this permission first,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then I suggest you to use this library to get json data from server
Use the following code block to replace your try catch block

https://github.com/koush/ion

```
Ion.with(context)
.load("http://example.com/thing.json")  // you can put any url here which when requested will    return you a json object
.asJsonObject()
.setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
@Override
public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
    // do stuff with the result or error
}
});
```

As you can see the json in browser then I think you are sending json data from your server in correct way.

Comment: yes i can able to see json data in browser correct way bt i don't knw how to read that in android-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your DNS parameters?? 
 error : unknownhostexception unable to resolve the host:www.xxxxxxxxx.com  could mean that your dns is bad!! replace your site name con IP if you know it.